# How do i connect my windows azure website with my domain name perfectly?

Tags: .htaccess, azure, azure-web-app-service

I did almost everything that have described in the azure documentation briefly.

My domain names that i need to be assigned with my azure website url `idaa.azurewebsites.net` are `mostout.com` and `www.mostout.com`.

When trying to enter my site using any of the links added here, the site loads and works perfectly as i need.

But the problem is with my url which is getting loaded in browser url field while giving `mostout.com` or `www.mostout.com`.

It comes with the **azure website url every time**. What do I do now to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the CNAME for your service: have the www. name point to the full azurewebsites.net address.

Note that you'll:

- need to have a level of service that supports custom domains with Windows Azure Web Sites,
- add the CNAME from your www. domain to the azurewebsites domain (same goes for having the naked domain name via an A record or similar)
- add the verification names, awverify.www.yourdomain.com and awverify.yourdomain.com
- use the Manage Domains function in the portal for the web site to customize that domain name,

Things should just work then.